# Adobe Right Management Server

Tags: pdf, adobe, drm, livecycle

I would like to have some of my pdf files to be DRM applied. I heard that Adobe Right Management Server has this facility. Please anybody describe me how this works? I want my forms to apply DRM protection. Please let me know ASAP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The search engines are your friends…

Adobe should have descriptions of the capabilities of LiveCycle Digital Rights (or whatever the name du jour is).

You might also look at FileOpen by FileOpen, including their services.

In general, keep in mind that with DRM, you get what you pay.